# I'm trying to randomly select one responce from Google Places NearbySearch call

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-places-api

I am trying to make a program that can call the Google Places Api and randomly return one of the responses. Currently, my code will take in 14 different keywords one by one and make a NearbySearch all for each. Then, when it is on it's last call, it needs to select one of those options to create a marker for. The problem is, when I run my code, it returns multiple markers in stead of 1... I don't know why this is.

Any thoughts as to what is causing the problem? (see relevant code below for reference)

```
function callback(results, status)
{
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
    {
        for(var i=0; i < ratings[i][2]; i++)
        {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length);
            recommendedFood.push(results[rand])
        }
    }
    if (last == true)
    {
        numlengths.push(recommendedFood.length)
        var final = Math.floor((Math.random() * recommendedFood.length));
        var obj = JSON.stringify(recommendedFood[final]);
        createMarker(recommendedFood[final])
    }
}

function createMarker(place)
{
    if (place != null)
    {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: place.geometry.location});

        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
        {
            infoWind.setContent(place.name);
            infoWind.open(map, this);
        });
    }                
}
```

Thanks for any input/advice you can give!

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle or jsbin so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?